# how can I select XML attribute from oracle XMLTYPE column?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I create table in oracle 12c like this

```
CREATE TABLE Test_xml
    (
       xml_data                       SYS.XMLTYPE
    )
```

and insert XML data like this into column xml_data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons xmlns="http://XXXXX.XXX/schema/1.0" name="ABC">
  <person>
    <name1 value="AAAA" />
    <name2 value="CCCC" />
    <name3 value="XXXX" />
  </person>
  <person>
    <name1 value="11111" />
    <name2 value="22222" />
    <name3 value="33333" />
  </person>
</persons>
```

but when I try to select data out from table by query

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM   Test_xml x,
       XMLTABLE('/persons/person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           name1  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH 'name1/@value'
         ) xt;
```

not thing out from the query,How can i select name1 from the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the (default, in this case) namespace as another argument to XMLTable:

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM   Test_xml x,
       XMLTABLE(
         xmlnamespaces(default 'http://XXXXX.XXX/schema/1.0'),
         '/persons/person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           name1  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH 'name1/@value'
         ) xt;
```

```
| NAME1 |
| :---- |
| AAAA  |
| 11111 |
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df44ea0056be4b05983801840937b211) showing your original query, @Sayan's wildcard version (which gets nulls for some reason, even though it works with a CTE), and this default namespace version.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `/persons/person` to `/*:persons/*:person`

```sql
SELECT/*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE */ xt.*
FROM   Test_xml x,
       XMLTABLE('/*:persons/*:person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           name1  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '*:name1/@value'
         ) xt;
```

Full example:

```sql
with test_xml(xml_data) as (
select xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons xmlns="http://XXXXX.XXX/schema/1.0" name="ABC">
  <person>
    <name1 value="AAAA" />
    <name2 value="CCCC" />
    <name3 value="XXXX" />
  </person>
  <person>
    <name1 value="11111" />
    <name2 value="22222" />
    <name3 value="33333" />
  </person>
</persons>]'
)
from dual
)
SELECT xt.*
FROM   Test_xml x,
       XMLTABLE('/*:persons/*:person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           name1  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '*:name1/@value'
         ) xt;

NAME1
--------------------
AAAA
11111
```

Comment: I try your query It work when it select from dual but if apply to the table, the result of name1 is null but return correct number of row in table. Am I missing something?

Comment: @maxzzxam did you notice `*:name1/@value`?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - I included your wildcard version in my db<>fiddle; and it doesn't work from a table. Not sure why, or why it would behave differently. Dumping the XML shows the same data type (58) but different lengths.

Comment: @AlexPoole huh! You found a bug in columns clause :) I've included another variant into you db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d357cdebd876850d9adddd9dd9798889

Comment: Re "different lengths": Though that's not ok, but it's understandable: oracle by default uses binary xml storage since 11.2 afair

Comment: Yes, extracted as strings they're the same, but again not sure why that would matter for your code. Your new variant works here but isn't going to be useful if you need several attributes from the node. `//@value` in the column path also works, but isn't useful if there are sub-nodes with a value attribute.

Comment: @AlexPoole just add hint `/*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE */` - it fixes that bug: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=566c1cff9af1ce8b26ee0be752ef099d

Comment: @MAXZZXAM please check updated query: I've added hint `/*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE */ ` to fix oracle bug with XML query optimization

Comment: OK, interesting. I still don't really like wildcarding the namespace, but at least it works now *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole yeah, I also don't like wildcarding when you absolutely sure in DTD schema and exact namespaces. But I often see, that namespaces or DTD schemas unexpectedly change or sometimes developers even don't have exact fixed DTD schemas and even worse when xml is partially invalid, especially in namespaces... Expecially when xml source is internet...

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I try by add /*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE */ but still out put as null

Comment: @MAXZZXAM - if it's a bug then behaviour, including workarounds, may vary depending on your exact Oracle version and patch level.

Comment: @MAXZZXAM have you added hint exactly after main `select` word? Show me please your exact query

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov here is my query

`SELECT/*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE */ xt.*
FROM   Test_xml x,
       XMLTABLE('/*:persons/*:person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           name1  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '*:name1/@value'
         ) xt;
`